# What does the following error mean?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
[Switching to process 388]
kill
error while killing target (killing anyway): warning: error on line 2179 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1472/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "macosx_kill_inferior_safe": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)
quit

The Debugger has exited with status 0.(gdb)
```

Comment: Definitely a very real question;  I've seen cases like this where that is just about the entirety of clue given.  Tough one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Program received signal:
>   “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. [Switching to
>   process 388] kill error while killing
>   target (killing anyway): warning:
>   error on line 2179 of
>   "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1472/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c"
>   in function
>   "macosx_kill_inferior_safe": (os/kern)
>   failure (0x5x) quit

Note where the error is;   `gdb` has crashed.   This is potentially due to a crash in your application, but that particular messages is certainly not useful to debugging the real problem.

And, more likely than not, the actual crash has *nothing* to do with an over-release of an object.  Maybe so, but likely not.

Typically, when GDB crashes in this fashion, it is because you trashed the heap or stack in a fashion that gdb trips over the corruption trying to figure out what is going on.  Or your app has entered a state that gdb can no longer communicate with it (which might be the case here given the crash location).

In this case, some things to try:

- using latest dev tools?  If not, do so and rebuild your app from clean, too.
- can the crash be reproduced on the simulator and the device?  If so, can it be debugged properly on one but not the other?
- if you run the app without the debugger, can you get it to crash and then extract the crash log from the device?
- does the behavior change between debug and non-debug builds?   That can greatly impact memory corruption.
- did this just start happening?  If so, what did you change most recently?

Thought of another trick;

- try setting the `MallocScribble` environment variable.  This will scribble values into memory upon allocation/deallocation and can often, at the least, cause a memory corruption related crasher to crash earlier or different enough to catch it.

Comment: I ended up upvoting the rest of the answers... they weren't *right* but they weren't punishable, either.   This is one of those **hard bugs**.  If you'd been doing straightforward development as a relative newcomer and ran into a situation like this, the assumption of over-release would be easy and natural... and entirely baffling as you try to figure out what the hell is actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` usually means you are trying to access something that doesn't exist anymore. We'd need your stack dump and probably some code to help you figure it out.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS only means that sometimes;  sometimes it means you stumbled on corrupt memory.  And, in this case, it is the debugger crashing which means the crash in the original app was likely not the typical retain/release issue.

Comment: why would the debugger crash, what could go wrong that doesn't source from an error in the op's code?

Comment: @6NSString: The debugger is a program. Programs can crash. Therefore, the debugger can crash. It could be a fault in gdb, it could be a fault in the program, it could be both—the next step for the questioner is to figure that out.

Comment: The debugger is a program that has bugs.  It also has to traipse through the memory of apps that have often gone off the rails.  Sometimes, that means running across corrupted data structures & sometimes the corruption is too much for the debugger and it crashes.

Comment: that's what I mean, the gdb crashed but it (likely) wouldn't have crashed if it was debugging code that hadn't corrupted memory.

Comment: Sure (Note I didn't downvote, btw), but EXC_BAD_ACCESS means something very simple;  you've attempted to use a chunk of garbage in memory as a valid address and the dereference caused a crash.  It doesn't mean that something doesn't exist; if I do `["bob's your uncle" length]` it'll likely crash w/EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Right. That's why i said 'usually' in my answer. That's my knee-jerk reaction to seeing EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Next time I'll read the error more closely!

Answer (score 0):

To quote a co-worker, "Something went wrong somewhere".

This means that you have attempted to access a pointer that is no longer valid. Perhaps you forgot to retain an object, or released it one too many times?

Comment: Nope -- this sequence means that **gdb** crashed.   The app probably crashed first and that was the trigger, but none of what is posted gives clues as to exactly what went wrong.   That the debugger crashed probably means the app corrupted memory above and beyond a simple over-release.